# Reading responseJson from MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC controller that returns Json results:

```
return Json(elements);
```

elements is a List

This is returned from an ajax call and I am processing the results in the OnComplete call.

In that call, I have everything I need, I can looks at the results and see the array of strings in responseJson but I can't figure out the syntax to get at the array.

```
function OverviewElementRemove_Complete(result) {
    $.each(result.responseJson, function (i, e) {
        //do some stuff?
    });
}
```

Again, to be clear, I can see the results I want in the debugger, I just don't know the syntax to loop through responseJson.

I know there are many questions similar to this but none cover this scenario.

Comment: There are a lot of information missing for people to answer this question.  What Type is elements?  What does the resulting JSON look like?

Comment: can you use result.elements[0]?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Sorry, my initial post had an issue, it should have indicated List<string>

Comment: @RossBush It seems to be undefined at least at this point

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but wouldn't `result` in your JS function be the list of strings? i.e.

```
result === ['string1', 'string2', 'etc.']
```

That's what i seem to get when i ran a basic test returning this:

```
return Json(new List<string>{"string1", "string2"});
```

So to loop through each item your code should just be:

```
function OverviewElementRemove_Complete(result) {
    $.each(result, function (i, e) {
        //do some stuff?
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fort those who didn't or couldn't read my original answer, here it is again.

Referring to "responseJson" (note the case) instead of "responseJSON" (again, note the case) is the problem.

Once I changed the reference to "responseJSON" (again, again, note the case) it worked.